# svn mkdir foo vs. mkdir foo; svn add foo

Tags: svn

I've seen in subversion tutorials that the way to add a folder to your repo is to do

```
 mkdir foo
 svn add foo
```

But running  svn mkdir foo does the same thing, as far as I can tell.  Is there a reason to mkdir then add instead of svn mkdir?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that `svn mkdir` can operate directly on a URL:

`svn mkdir svn://remote.host/what/ever`

Answer (score 0):

There's no functional different that I'm aware of.

One is simply longer to type than the other and potentially you could forget to `svn add` if you got out of the habit of using `svn mkdir`.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, applications that do version control don't manage file attributes. From this point "mkdir foo; svn add foo" can be more flexible in some scenarios.